# Star pattern using string and string manipulation in c++

Tags: c++, string

This code prints star pattern.

```
// CPP Program to print 
// pattern using std::setw and std::fill 
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> // std::setfill, std::setw 

int main() 
{ 
    int n = 5; 
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { 
        std::cout << std::left << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(n); 
        std::cout << std::string(i, '*') << std::endl; 
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't know how `std::string(i,'*')` works.
And if I write only `std::cout << std::string(i, '*') << std::endl;` then getting nothing in the output.

Comment: Did you include <string> in your cpp source ?

Comment: @FahimAhmed It is not showing any compilation error or warning. But when I remove the first statement from the for loop it doesn't print anything.

Comment: part from the missing `#include <string>` it looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how std::string(i,'*') works

Check the documentation for the constructor `std::string(count, ch)` on [this site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). I find C++'s documentation hard to read, so what it says about that constructor is:

```
basic_string( size_type count,
              CharT ch,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

Constructs the string with "count" copies of character "ch".
```

So what it means is, you pass it one number `n` and one char `c`, and it will return a string that has `n` copies of `c`. So if you call `std::string(4, 'A')` it will return `AAAA`.

> if I write only std::cout << std::string(i, '*') << std::endl; then getting nothing in the output.

I don't quite get which change you did to the program to not get any output, as only `std::cout << std::string(i, '*') << std::endl;` inside the loop should still print something.

Check [the docs for `std::left`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) which have a nice example that uses `std::fill` and `std::setw` too.

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't know how std::string(i,'*') works

Check out this link [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/).

Specially check out the constructor

```
string (size_t n, char c);
```

What this constructor does is , it returns **a string object containing *n* number of *c* characters**.

Your code seems to be working fine in GNU C++. Check this out [codeLink](https://ideone.com/Zk9rMC). Which compiler are you using to run it?

Answer (score 0):

This exact same code works for me. Maybe a problem with your compiler or you are doing something stupid like running the wrong executable or something.
[image]